# Analyzing code path in Objective C a la TraceGL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

TraceGL is a pretty neat project that allows JS programmers to trace code paths in Javascript. It looks something like this:

[image]

I'd like to build something similar for Objective C. I know the runtime has made it rather easy to trace method calls, but how would I trace control flow? For example, in the screenshot above, code paths not executed are made obvious with a red highlight. What would be the best way to achieve something similar in an Objective C/Xcode workflow?

The best I've come up with so far is to write a preprocessor that injects code into temporary source files before sending them to the compiler. Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: What are you trying to get out of doing this? If you want code coverage, there already exist code coverage tools (gcov if using gcc, and libprofile_rt for clang).

Comment: hi anon! I am merely planning to build something like trace GL for runtime objective C code. i am not particularly interested in static analysis.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. [Code Coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) is not static analysis. Code coverage requires you to run your app, and then it tells you which lines of code were executed, similar to what you've described above.

Comment: sorry anon, you're 100% right and I did misunderstand. seems like gconv/libprofile_rt counts how many times a piece of code has been executed, which is really close to what I want! is one able to associate each time a line of code is run with a trace? in other words, if line X is called first in code path A, then again in code path B, can the analyzer tell me line X was called in code paths A and B?

Comment: any thoughts @user1118321?

Comment: I've only used code coverage a little bit, so I don't know the answer off the top of my head. But there's plenty of documentation on `gcov` and `gprof`. I haven't used libprofile_rt, but it appears to replace `gcov` and generates `gprof` files, so that's probably the best place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly answer for Objective C and XCode.

For C++ code there is a industrial quality code coverage tool [BullseyeCoverage](http://www.bullseye.com/productInfo.html)

> - Function coverage gives you a quick overview and condition/decision coverage gives you high precision
> - Works with everything you can write in C++ and C, including system-level and kernel mode

If you want to invent/write this kind of tool yourself I'd recommend to take a look at (evaluate) some existing tools that solve the same task so that you don't miss a key functionality

There are basically **2 categories** of such tools

- working at binary level, **instrument byte code**, library entry points etc.
- working at source level, **instrument source code** before going to the compiler

The purpose of the instrumentation is to insert into the code **calls to a profiling runtime** that collects the runtime statistics for further processing.

Basic calls

- timestamp, thread id, source code address, **entering**
- timestamp, thread id, source code address, **leaving**

The source code address depends on the granularity you are interesetd in. It can be a function name ot it can be a source file and line number.

Collected performance data can be quite huge so they are usually summed-up and whole callstacks are not captured. It is usually sufficient level of detail for detecting performance bottlenecks.

Another drawback is that capturing detailed performance data especially in code points with many hits will slow the application significantly.

If you want complete history then capture the full trace including timestamps and thread-ids and you will be able to recreate the call stacks later knowing that each `enter` has corresponding `leave`.

To guarantee this pairing the code instrumentation must insert exception handling calls to make sure that exit point will be logged even if the function throws an exception (what is the "exception" and how to try-finally it dependes on the language and the OS platform).

To get all necessary tricks and tips **evaluate some tools and take a look at their instrumentation style**.

BTW: in general it is quite a lot of work to do and to get right I'd personally thought twice or more times about what will be the outcome and what will be the costs.

As a want-to-play-with topic I fully recommend that. I created such a tool for troubleshooting Java MIDP applications working at C++ source level and Java binary level and it was helpful at the time when we needed it.

Comment: This is pretty awesome information! If no one else responds with an Xcode/Objective C specific answer before the bounty expires, be sure to tell me and I'll give you the answer.

Comment: @Dany ok, if no one else responds and you need to spend your earned-reputation you can give it to me :) One thing that would be costly and you should take into account that whether you'll use source level or binary level access is: you'll need some kind of ```parser``` so that you inject the instrumentation correctly. and C++ is not an easy language to parse (preprocessor etc.), C is easier but unless your code follows some strict rules you will need a "real" parser with simplified Abstract Syntax Tree etc.. do some parser/grammar research before starting..

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Right now I'm thinking about doing it at the language level since I'll be interested in capturing control flow (did an if statement evaluate?) as well as method calls.

Comment: @Dany the simplest way to start some prototyping would be to skip creation of the automatic preprocessor with parser and stuff. Just define calls to the profiling runtime as C macros and scatter them around your source code manually at places you need them.. my rough optimistic estimate for the preprocessor once you have found the parsing libraries is ~5 man/days.. so I'd start simple doing things manually and automating them later (I'm trying to be useful :)

Comment: yeah, definitely would start with runtime instrumentation first. the code parsing bit will be the most challenging, in terms of creating an objective C port for this!

Answer (score 6):

I guess the visualizer for issues found by Xcode's static analyzer comes pretty close to this - albeit this one will only give you the call path for a particular issue like a memory leak.

Try *"Product > Analyze"* in Xcode, select any of the issues found on any given project and click on the blue arrow in the code editor to see for yourself.

[image]

Comment: whoa, this is pretty neat! this is a great start, except I suppose I would need this functionality for runtime. any idea if the static analyzer is available as an open source project? does it make sense for a runtime version of this to exist?

Comment: Welllll.... it even has **static** in the name, so it's rather doing the opposite. Not sure how much of this is Open Source, though. Much of the underlying clang compiler sure is

Comment: got it! thanks for your help. Seems like messing with gcov/libprofile_rt might be my best bet so far.

Comment: I think some of the trace display bits are included with Clang--you can get analyzer output as HTML. (I think)