# Is there a free or low cost tool like TraceGL for C# to record functions called/parameters sent?

Tags: c#, trace

TraceGL is a cool tracing tool for javascript showing which functions executed and with what parameters they were called, as well as showing the value of variables in the source cod--- see this question [Analyzing code path in Objective C a la TraceGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125013/analyzing-code-path-in-objective-c-a-la-tracegl) for a picture of it.

See https://github.com/traceglMPL/tracegl.

Spy-JS also does something similar for the WebStorm IDE.

I would like a low cost/tool like this in C#----Intellitrace seems to be only available in Visual Studio Ultimate.

If possible, I'd like also record statements executed and variable values, as TraceGL and Spy-js for Webstorm does. I don't necessarily need this in prod, could be for a local dev environment.

Is there anything that would do this or do it in part?

Comment: Intellitrace comes in the Enterprise version of VS2015, which can be obtained for the same price as 2013 Professional via MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be using a profiler - either the built-in, or something like [NP.NET profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35370), that will dump the callstack.